# Substitute element on a octave matrices

Tags: matrix, find, octave, substitution

I want to substitute all the element in a matrices comprises between a range. I try to use this method (just simple code for exhample):

```
A = rand(5);
A(A>0 && A<0.5) = 0.5;
```

But didn't work. This one work:

```
A = rand(5);
for j = 1:5
  for i = 1:5
    if A(i,j)>0 && A(i,j)<0.5
      A(i,j) = 0.5;
    endif
  endfor
endfor
```

But it is very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost there:

```
A = rand(5);
A(A>0 & A<0.5) = 0.5;
```

See [Element-by-element boolean operator](https://octave.org/doc/v5.1.0/Element_002dby_002delement-Boolean-Operators.html#Element_002dby_002delement-Boolean-Operators). You've used `&&` which is a Short-circuit Boolean Operator.